Simple way in detecting astable solution from Differential Algebraic Equation
I have a semi-explicit DAE (Differential Algebraic Equation) with the following form:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\dot{s}} &= \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{s}, \mathbf{x}) \\
\mathbf{0} &= \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{s}, \mathbf{x})
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{R}^M$ is the states variable and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is the algebraic variable. Given that I have the functions $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{g}$, are there any numerical way to check if the system would be astable without having to numerically solve the equations?
As an example of astable system, consider the case where $M=N=1$,
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= \tanh[A(x - 2s)] - x \\
\dot{s} &= x - s
\end{align}
$$
with $A \gg 1$. If we start at $s=0$ and $x=1$, the system's $x$ will oscillate indefinitely  between 1 and -1 (see below). It is neither converge to a value nor diverge to infinity.

Repeating my question: given $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{g}$, is there a simple numerical way to check whether the system is astable without having to numerically solve the equations?

Shouldn't the following work: linearize your nonlinear DAE to get a linear DAE of the form $E\dot{x}=Ax$, then evaluate the eigenvalues of the matrix pencil $(E,A)$ to check stability. This should tell you something about the stability of the system at least locally. For global stability of nonlinear DAEs, I guess you are out of luck. There isn't even a "simple numerical way" (as you put it) for the easier case when there are no equality constraints (i.e. for a general nonlinear differential equation).

By the way, your initial condition $s=0,x=1$ is invalid because it doesn't satisfy the equality constraint. In fact, $\tanh(x)<1$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so if $x=1$ the equality constraint can never be satisfied for real $x$.

@SampleTime I don't think the behaviour above can be captured by linearization, as the oscillation is caused by changing the root's location. The initial condition $x=1$ is just an approximate, as $A \gg 1$. For example, if you have $A = 10^5$ with $s = 0$, we would have $x \approx 1 - e^{-2\times 10^5}$, which is practically 1.

Yes, practially thats approximately true but for stability theory this will be shaky ground I guess. However, I think the problem is also ill posed, because for $s\in(-0.5,0.5)$ you should have two possible solutions for $x$, right? If I plot $y(x)=\tanh[A(x-2s)]-x$ with $A=10^5$ and constant $s\in(-0.5,0.5)$, then the graph has two zero crossings. So I don't think the solution of your example is unique and in fact there are many solutions that aren't astable.

@SampleTime the equations are derived from the astable circuit well-known to generate indefinitely oscillating signals. For example, see here. It is true that $y(x)$ has >1 zero crossings (either at 1 or -1). What we assume is if in the previous time step is $x=1$ (or $x=-1$), then the value of $x$ at the next time step will be $x=1$ (or $x=-1$) if it's still possible. When $s$ exceeds 0.5 (or -0.5), only $x=-1$ (or $x=1$) crossing that is possible, so the value of $x$ will change.

Yes, I suspected that, but then the equations in your question are incomplete because they admit other solutions as well. I would recommend to update your main question to include this information, as this notion of "memory" adds hysteresis to your system.
